# Is my timing of giving hints good?

Tags: discussion, hints

Starting with [this question,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90639/62436) I shall give hints on specific timing.

1. After 24 hours since posting the question, I give a **subtle** hint.
2. After other 12 hours, I give a **moderate** hint.
3. After other 6 hours, I give a **decisive** hint.
4. For each inaccurate answers, my (abstract) timer resets.

Is this a good timing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deusovi's answer is great, but I would also like to add that a *perfect* puzzle should not require hints.  Of course, designing the perfect puzzle is extremely difficult if not impossible, but we should always be striving to create puzzles that can be solved on their own (even if it takes a long time).

And just because it hasn't been solved in a day (or a week, or a month) doesn't mean that people aren't actively working on a solution.  I have had a couple of experiences where I spend hours or days on a puzzle, but before I get to posting my solution, a hint is posted that basically gives away the answer.

There is a difference between *difficult* and *obscure*.  A difficult puzzle may take a long time to solve, but should be solvable without hints.  An obscure puzzle contains insufficient information in the puzzle to be able to reasonably solve it (without some massive intuitive leap that is unlikely to happen).

TL;DR:  Try to make puzzles that don't require hints.  If that can't be avoided, make them few and sparing, and not very often.

Answer (score 9):

No, for two main reasons:

- It sounds like, if nobody knows the answer for 24+12+6 hours, you will give a hint that likely gives a large part of the puzzle away. That is *far* too short an amount of time for that.
- If someone gives a wrong answer, your timer resets. Why? It looks like you're 'punishing' people for making attempts then -- you're actively discouraging people from trying out answers.

I would go with a hint every 24-48 hours that no progress has been made (whether or not any answers have been posted), gradually increasing the usefulness of the hints.

Comment: My timer resets because wrong answers are hints themselves.

Comment: What about the question I linked? Do you think the decisive hint is as decisive as you concerned?